# How to make a string cipher with specified length

Tags: java, md5

I am trying to make a brute force application that takes the input of a simple MD5 hash and the user specifies the length of the password originally. From there i use a class that goes trough all the possibilities. So for example..

the word "password" in MD5 would become `5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99`. the program would start from `aaaaaaaa` then iterate to `aaaaaaab` and so on, and will be converted to MD5 and compared with the users input.

the problem i'm having is how do i make a string, with the character length the the user has specified, iterate trough all the letters in the alphabet. Instinctively i tried this:

```
public String calculateHash() throws InterruptedException
{
    //pass is length 1
    if(length > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            //pass is length 2
            if(length > 1)
            {
                for(int x=0; x < alphabet.length; x++)
                {
                    if(length > 2)
                    {
                        for(int y=0; y < alphabet.length; y++)
                        {
                            if(length > 3)
                            {
                                for(int z=0; z < alphabet.length; z++)
                                {
                                    if(length > 4)
                                    {
                                        for(int v=0; v < alphabet.length; v++)
                                        {
                                            if(length > 5)
                                            {
                                                for(int f=0; f < alphabet.length; f++)
                                                {
                                                    if(length >= 6)
                                                    {
                                                        for(int g=0; g < alphabet.length; g++)
                                                        {

                                                         //character would be added to the end of the string.
```

After the iterations are complete the finished string will be sent to a method to hash it and returned. but there has to be a more efficient way to go about this.

Comment: You miss a lot `}`. Seriously: you need to overthink your design.

Comment: The runtime of this is ridiculous. There are also better ways to "generate all permutations of the alphabet"

Comment: i cut it out because having 12 lines of curly brackets are irrelevant

Comment: How do you know the password was alphabetic only? No upper-case? No digits? No special characters? and finally, do you have any idea how long this is going to take to run? You will be in the retirement home before it finishes.

Comment: This is just a small little program i'm doing out of boredom before i start back in college. i'm only going to be using lowercase letters and words with a small character length (around 6 or 7). plus MD5 is one of the easier hashing algorithms to brute force, especially as i'm not going to be salting anything.

Comment: @aaronward Well, your instincts took you to this horrible construct. Luckily you don't trust your instincts too much and realized that this is ridiculous. Now how else could you create a String of `N` characters and iterate all the combinations? Imagine doing it for numbers first, so you've got `"0000"` (a `String` mind you) and you need to go all the way to `"9999"`.